# MobiScroll & jqMobi & jqUI

Tags: mobiscroll, jqmobi

Has anyone gotten the Mobiscroll plugins to work on a App created with jqMobi & jqUI? I am have difficulty getting the scrollers to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No known issues with the mentioned combination.

Make sure the js is loaded before the initialization of the controls.

Comment: Got it working, just had another question about height and width. Se up another S/O question about it.